# standard deviation and adjusted R-squared for simultaneous regressions

Tags: statistics, regression

I am conducting a study that requires two steps of statistical estimation. First, I run a regular OLS regression, from which I gather three outputs that I need:

1. coefficient values
2. standard deviations for these values
3. adjusted R-squared

Second, I estimate a system of two simultaneous questions and run a vector regression. MatLab gives me the following outputs: coefficient estimates, covariance matrix for dependent variables, matrix of residuals, covariance matrix of the estimates, and the log-likelihood function. I am not sure what to make of these information and how it corresponds to the first simple OLS regression. I have only the coefficient values, but not the other two things. How can I find the standard deviation and the adjusted R-squared (or their closest substitutes) in the case of two simultaneous regressions?

Comment: i dont know how to do this is matlab but i wrote formulas for these before here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067488/adjusted-r-squared-with-multiple-dependent-varialbles/1067510#1067510

Comment: i don't think this is a correct answer because of the covariances and such

Comment: for Adjusted R squared thats a correct answer i provided a book name i recommend you look in the book it is the correct formula

Comment: McElroy R-squared is perhaps what I need: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93751/goodness-of-fit-of-a-sur-model  but how do I find the variance-covariance matrix of the residuals?